# Rails 4 and Turbolinks - Meta Tags not changing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have a Rails 4 app with turbo-links enabled, but I can't get the meta tags to refresh when changing the page ( not a full refresh ) . I read that the meta-tags need to be included before the javascript that loads the turbo-links but it has no effect. A full refresh does the job, but unfortunately this is not what i search for.

layout/application.html.haml

```
%html
  %head
    %title= "Title"
    - if content_for?(:meta_description)
      %meta{content: (yield :meta_description), name: "description"}/
      %meta{content: (yield :meta_keywords), name: "keywords"}/
    = stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true 
    = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true

    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body{class: params[:controller].gsub("/", "-"), id: 'top'}
    = render "shared/header"
    .body-content
      = render "shared/flash"
      = yield
    = render "shared/footer"
    = render "shared/analytics"
```

helpers/application_helper.rb

> def meta_tag(title, description)
>
> ```
> content_for :meta_keywords do
>   title
> end
>
> content_for :meta_description do
>   description
> end
> ```
>
> end

And this is how I call them

```
= meta_tag('here s my title', 'and the keywords')
```

Thanks

Comment: I know it's not really helping or answering the question, but most search engines don't use meta keywords anymore.

Comment: why do you need the meta tags (other than csrf token) to refresh on client-side?

Answer (score 24):

#### How Turbolinks works

Turbolinks is designed to keep the `<head>` tag the same and merely replaces the `<body>` tag with the contents of the requested page via an AJAX request. Since your `<meta>` tags are located in the `<head>`, they won't be changed via a Turbolinks request.

#### What about SEO?

From an SEO perspective, you don't need to worry about the `<meta>` tags being updated on a Turbolinks request because the search engine crawlers will always do a full page request and won't execute the Turbolinks javascript.

From a user's perspective, the only tag in the `<head>` that needs to change for each request is the `<title>` tag, so special handling for that was built-in to Turbolinks itself.

#### Will this behavior ever change?

This "issue" has been raised and shot down a couple times, each time being declared a non-issue by DHH himself, so I wouldn't count on this behavior changing any time soon.

See:

- https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/81
- https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/pull/165

Comment: I have disabled turbolinks. But, still my page is not reloading completely. It doesn't change the head tag and doesn't load the page-specific css through content_for tag. Can you suggest what could be the problem?

Comment: I'd be happy to help you with your issue, but you should post it as a separate SO post so the rest of the community can help as well. Please include as much detail as possible including how you disabled turbo links. Post the link to the new question and I'll do my best to help.

Comment: Another tag in `<head>` than is affected is `<meta property="og:image" content="...` . nobody change this tag, to get a nice "sharer" for facebook?

Comment: Is this still true today? "search engine crawlers will always do a full page request and won't execute the Turbolinks javascript"

Comment: Unlike earlier versions, Turbolinks versions from v5 onward do update meta tags, and any other provisional elements in the document <head>.

Source: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/issues/158#issuecomment-237697926

Answer (score 2):

**It's a TurboLinks Problem**

By design, Turbolinks basically keeps the `<head>` of your page the same & calls the `<body>` of your document via ajax if it's going to remain the same (you're using the same controller / action). It's some crazy thing to maintain application performance

Here is a [**good explanation of Turbolinks**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231616/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-asset-pipeline-turbolinks-from-rails-4-for-a-big-a)

---

I've had a similar problem to this with Javascript, and was able to use the [Jquery-Turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem to keep JS rendering

For your meta tags, although I don't know a solution off hand, I managed to find a decent gem you might benefit from: [`MetaMagic`](https://github.com/lassebunk/metamagic). It allows you to define meta tags in the view, kind of like how the content_block facility works. This should be loaded on every http request

Comment: I tried metamagic but it doesn't help. As far as I understand, metamagic does basically the same thing, the "yield" in the header, and the "content_for" in the views, so the metatags from the header, are still unchanged. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: No problem - if I find anything, I'll update the answer for you!

Comment: I have a similar problem right now. Something new on this topic?

Comment: What's up? Maybe we can help

Comment: Nothing new, I still don't have an answer. Anyway, the good news is that google takes all the links from a webpage, and renders each one separately, so from SEO perspective, the meta tags still do their job.

Answer (score 1):

I extend the current turbolinks js ;)

It will replace meta tags and canonical link!

https://github.com/philklei/turbolinks

Comment: Thank you a lot for sharing this. Though links to offsite pages may become invalid, therefor consider adding or explaining your extension here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on [meta-tags gem](https://github.com/kpumuk/meta-tags)

"Using with pjax" section