# Rails authenticity_token on a form vs csrf token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csrf, authenticity-token

On same page of a rails 4 app I have a

in the head:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="some_token" />
```

and below in the body:

```
<form action="/someaction" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="another_token" />
```

The csrf token is need for js calls. But why is the form token different from the csrf token? Which of the two tokens is used on form submission?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've made some researches to answer your question, and here are results.

First of all, let's look at this part:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="some_token" />
```

This part is generated by method [csrf_meta_tags](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/csrf_helper.rb#L19). From the source code we can see that:

1. "content" attribute value of `<meta name="csrf-param" />` is taken from [request_forgery_protection_token](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L90), and, by default, is `:authenticity_token`.
2. "content" attribute value of `<meta name="csrf-token" />` is taken from [form_authenticity_token](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L196) method, where the token is either taken from session, or generated.

Now let's check out this part:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="another_token" />
```

From the source we can see that:

1. This hidden input is returned by [extra_tags_for_form](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L747) method.
2. Inside `extra_tags_for_form` invokes [token_tag](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L621) method.
3. `token_tag` method takes the token as the argument.
4. `token` argument for `token_tag` is previously extracted from `options` argument of [form_tag](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L66) method in [html_options_for_form](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L724) method.

So if you didn't manually set `authenticity_token` param in `options` to your custom token and didn't meet the conditions that lead to setting `token` value to false (will be mentioned below), `token_tag` method will receive `nil` and invoke the same [form_authenticity_token](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L196) method that is used for the `<meta name="csrf-token" />` tag creating. By the way, for filling `name` attribute of input it also uses [request_forgery_protection_token](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L90), that is used when `<meta name="csrf-param" />` tag generation occurs.

And because this all occurs during the same request, invocation of `form_authenticity_token` method should return the same result in both cases.

> Which of the two tokens is used on form submission?

On form submission will be used the token from hidden input.

Token from `<meta />` also can be used, but only if all of below [conditions](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb#L734) (that make `token` argument of `token_tag` method be set to false) will be met:

1. `:remote => true` should be passed in `options` of `form_tag`.
2. `embed_authenticity_token_in_remote_forms` config is set to false.
3. `authenticity_token` wasn't passed in `options`.

> But why is the form token different from the csrf token?

As for this question, maybe this problem occurs because of caching. Or, probably, if you use Turbolinks gem, it might cause this issue (you can check this if you totally refresh the page and compare tokens once again). For more info about problem with Turbolinks, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19463978/rails-4-and-turbolinks-meta-tags-not-changing).

Comment: +1 for Turbolinks. I had InvalidAuthenticityToken issues because the page was not fully reloaded and the token in the page was different from the one in the `meta` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to this other question, in which I left an answer:

[CSRF token error occurs when using turbolinks with ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55040734/csrf-token-error-occurs-when-using-turbolinks-with-ruby-on-rails/69699490#69699490)